# Optimizing code in java/XML - Android development

Tags: android, optimization, android-layout

I have some buttons laid out in `RelativeLayout` format and I wanna put the last button right below the the second last but also in the middle of the screen. Initially, when my buttons were one below the other, my XML file looked somewhat like this:

// some buttons

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ok"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry"
        android:text="Cancel" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickdate"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/cancel"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:text="Set Date" />
```

but when I wanted to set the `LeftMargin` of the "set date" button (last one) to `"width of screen" / 2`, I had to code it in Java, obtaining the width using `getWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay()`. But on executing it, it seemed as if the XML attributes defined for the last button (Layout Parameters only) were all getting ignored. I guess that's because the java code is parsed after the XML, and it overrides the behavior  defined in XML. I had to set **all** layout attributes in Java src file itself. Here is the Java code:

```
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int w = display.getWidth();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(w/2, 25, 0, 0);
        params.width = 200;
        params.height = 50;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.cancel);
        datepick.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For just one attribute. I had to set **all** the attributes in Java. Is there any way around this ? Something like referencing my variable `w` in XML.. any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its not clear what you are trying to do here? Are you simply trying to have a vertical list of buttons in the center of the screen? Why not just set the gravity on the ViewGroup to `center`?

Comment: I'm learning how to use different layouts in android..Basically I have a list of buttons, but lets talk about just one button. I wanna put the button in the middle of the screen, ie., I want to calculate its LeftMargin at runtime, so obviously XML won't be able to do that for me...So I did that using Java and had to re-define all the attributes again, since the LayoutParams in XML were being ignored the moment it encountered datepick.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: I don't want to define all parameters again (width, height, relative to what), but only Margin. How to do that?

Comment: If you want to put a button in the center of the screen you don't need to calculate the left margin

Comment: Supposing its not just center..I simply have to calculate or rather "change" an attribute at runtime, I will have to do it in Java..right

Comment: If you want to make any changes are runtime you must do them in java. In fact the XML files you define get compiled into java.